# Ajax call in Grails leads to "Could not find matching constructor"

Tags: ajax, grails

I use the grails formRemote tag to add an item to a dropdown list "on the fly".  The item does get added, but when I submit the main form I get:

```
Could not find matching constructor for: VarnType(java.lang.String)
```

where Varn is the domain object being created in the main form and VarnType is the domain object listed in the dropdown,the list I am adding to with formRemote.
Here is the formRemote usage:

```
<g:form url="[resource:varnInstance, action:'save']" id="mainV">
            <fieldset class="form">
                <g:render template="form"/>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="buttons">
                <g:submitButton name="create" class="save" value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" />
            </fieldset>
        </g:form>
        <g:formRemote name="vTypeForm"
                      url="[controller:'varnType', action:'createVarnTypeOnTheFly']"
                      update="varnType">
            <input type="text" name="typeName" >
            <input type="submit" value="Create Varn Type!">
        </g:formRemote>
```

Thinking that the VarnType object needed another constructor with an argument of String, I added it, but got, in the controller of the Varn domain object itself:

```
Class
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException
Message
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the 
transient instance before flushing
```

I don't understand why the Varn domain object (the parent object) is trying to persist a VarnType (child object) that was already created via the formRemote.  Is there an additional step I should take to make this object available to Grails?

EDIT:  Here is controller code:

```
def createVarnTypeOnTheFly(){

    VarnType vt = new VarnType(params)
    vt.save flush: true
    render(template: '/config/varnTypeOptions',model:[optionList: VarnType.list()])
}
```

Here is the entity relationship:

```
class VarnType {
String typeName

static constraints = {
}

static mapping = {
    id column:"varn_type_id"
    id generator: "sequence",params: [sequence:"scan_sequence"]
}

String toString(){
    return typeName
}

}
```

VarnType:

```
class Varn {
    Application app
    Assessment assessment
    String varnName
    String recommendation
    String httpMethod
    VarnType varnType
    String varnNote
    String param
    Risk risk
    String urlParam
    Date dateFound
    Date dateReported
    Date dateFixed
    static hasMany = [varnNotes:AppNote]

    static constraints = {
        varnName nullable: true
        urlParam nullable: true
        risk nullable: true
        recommendation nullable: true
        assessment nullable: true

    }
    static mapping = {
        id column:'varn_id'
        id generator: 'sequence',params:[sequence:'scan_sequence']
    }

    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include some controller code and how you define the relationship for Varn and VarnType?

Answer (score 3):

I expect that you have a request parameter named `varnType` and you are doing something like `new Varn(params)`.  When the data binder tries to initialize the `varnType` property in the `Varn` instance, since you haven't told it otherwise it us trying to call `new VarnType(params.varnType)`, which fails.

If you want the binder to be able to create an instance of `VarnType` from a String you will need to do something like provide a custom `Converter` or use the `BindUsing` annotation.  All of that is covered in the user guide.  See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding.